# How to add or append the selected checkbox in a row into $(form).serialize() using DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery DataTables I implement multiple selection of users in a table. My problem is how to add or append the selected checkbox in a row into the $(form).serialize() before submitting? And how to do console.log the data selected checkbox in row?

I use this following library:

https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.7/js/dataTables.checkboxes.js
https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.7/css/dataTables.checkboxes.css

DataTables jQuery Configuration:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    var usersTable = $("#users-table").DataTable({
                        ajax: {
                            url: GetBaseUrl() + URL_USER_LIST,
                            type: "GET",
                            dataSrc: function(data) {
                                return data;
                            }
                        },
                        responsive: true,
                        lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
                        bPaginate: true,
                        bFilter: false,
                        bInfo: false,
                        bLengthChange: false,
                        bAutoWidth: false,
                        columnDefs: [
                            {
                                targets: 0,
                                data: null,
                                defaultContent: "",
                                orderable: false,
                                className: "select-checkbox",
                                checkboxes: {
                                    seletRow: true
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                targets: 1,
                                data: "FullName",
                                orderable: false,
                                render: function(data) {
                                    return data;
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                targets: 2,
                                data: "EmailAddress",
                                orderable: false,
                                render: function(data) {
                                    return data;
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        select: {
                            style: "multi"
                        },
                        order: [[1, "asc"]]
                    });

                    $(document).on("click",
                        "button",
                        function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            const result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked', usersTable.rows().nodes()).map(
                                function() {
                                    return this.value;
                                }).get();

                            console.log(result);
                        });

                });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">


 <table id="users-table" class="table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-responsive display select" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tfoot>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

SUBMIT:

```
                $(container).on(eventClick,
                    btnClassSave,
                    function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        window.common._save(container,
                            GetBaseUrl() + URL_SAVE,
                            $(".users-form").serialize(),
                            "listview",
                            widget._saveSuccess);
                    });

 <button class="btn btn-success save-button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Save
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default cancel-button" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel
                    </button>
```

Comment: Will you include your .submit() code?

Comment: @JerdineSabio thanks for the reply. I updated it. Please see.

Comment: Do those checkbox have names?

Comment: yes, they're have.

Comment: what is the name of the checkbox? To clarify the name attribute in input `<input type="checkbox" name="test">`

Comment: select-checkbox, it just like this  targets: 0,
                                data: null,
                                defaultContent: "",
                                orderable: false,
                                className: "select-checkbox",
                                checkboxes: {
                                    seletRow: true
                                }

Comment: so the name attribute is `name="select-checkbox"`, is that correct? Because what I notice there is it's just a class name declaration, it has to be the name attribute. Will you post a screenshot of the result html. We need to verify the name attribute of the checkbox.

Comment: @JerdineSabio I uploaded the image. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SUBMIT code snippet you have provided, you have

```
$(".users-form").serialize()
```

so you are serializing all form data and performing submit.

```
var data = $(".users-form").serialize() + "&checkBoxId=" + checkBoxValue;
```

This will append checkbox value to form data, Use the **data** to post your form value, as shown below.

```
var data = $(".users-form").serialize() + "&checkBoxId=" + checkBoxValue;

 $(container).on(eventClick,
                    btnClassSave,
                    function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        window.common._save(container,
                            GetBaseUrl() + URL_SAVE,
                            data,
                            "listview",
                            widget._saveSuccess);
                    });
```

Try this implementation that serializes datatable form data.

$(document).ready(function (){
   var table = $('#example1').DataTable({
      pageLength: 4
   });

// Handle form submission event
   $('#frm-example1').on('submit', function(e){
      var form = this;

```
  // Encode a set of form elements from all pages as an array of names and values
  var params = table.$('input,select,textarea').serializeArray();

  // Iterate over all form elements
  $.each(params, function(){
     // If element doesn't exist in DOM
     if(!$.contains(document, form[this.name])){
        // Create a hidden element
        $(form).append(
           $('<input>')
              .attr('type', 'hidden')
              .attr('name', this.name)
              .val(this.value)
        );
     }
  });
```

});
});

For more info refer this.

https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-submit-all-pages-form-data/

Comment: nice! but how to console the row data if you click the checkbox in a row? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the output of .serialize() is just a url encoded string, You could append to the serialize like this;

`var data = $(".users-form").serialize()+"&checkbox1=VALUE"+"&checkbox2=VALUE";`

Try the snippet below.

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // store form values to variable data
  var data = $("form").serialize();

  // loop through checked checkboxes
  $(".input-checkbox:checked").each(function() {
  
    // append its value to variable data
    data += "&" + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).val();
  });

  // show serialized string
  console.log(data);
});
```

```css
table {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="name" />
  <input name="email" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Checkbox 1</th>
      <th>Checkbox 2</th>
      <th>Checkbox 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" value="test1" /></td>
      <td><input name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" value="test2" /></td>
      <td><input name="checkbox3" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" value="test3" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To console log the row data, I think you could use .parent() or .parents("tr");

```
$("input[type="checkbox"]:checked").each(function(){
    // the first .parent() is to navigate to the TD
    // the second .parent() is to navigate to the TR
    console.log($("this").parent().parent());

    // show the html content of the second column;
    console.log($("this").parent().parent().find("td").eq(1).html());
});
```

nice! but how to console the row data if you click the checkbox in a row? thanks

Comment: nice! but how to console the row data if you click the checkbox in a row? thanks

Comment: Hi @Fred I updated the code, you could navigate to the specific column using combination of .parent() and .find()

Comment: greate help Jerdine! I really hate datatables. haha thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi @Fred do consider this as the right answer, so we could close this. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, it's not I cannot console log the row data if I click the datatables row

Comment: using this, $("input[type="checkbox"]:checked").each(function(){
    // the first .parent() is to navigate to the TD
    // the second .parent() is to navigate to the TR
    console.log($("this").parent().parent());

    // show the html content of the second column;
    console.log($("this").parent().parent().find("td").eq(1).html());
});

Comment: I see. Please include the *result html* from your web page. So we could make a script to navigate to it.

Answer (score 0):

if you're in .NET, ensure that you have the `name` attribute of the checkbox set to the property you want to bind to.